# Error message in Neovim during autocompletion: `Error executing vim.schedule lua callback`

Tags: neovim

I have been struggling finding a solution to this problem and haven't found a solution to it so far. To be honest I don't understand it.

```
Error executing vim.schedule lua callback: ...w/Cellar/neovim/0.8.1/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp.lua:2018: attempt to index field 'range' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ...w/Cellar/neovim/0.8.1/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp.lua:2018: in function 'adjust_start_col'
        ...w/Cellar/neovim/0.8.1/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp.lua:2094: in function 'handler'
        ...w/Cellar/neovim/0.8.1/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp.lua:1383: in function ''
        vim/_editor.lua: in function <vim/_editor.lua:0>
```

It seems to be related to lsp but it's not pointing to any of the files in my config.

It happens during autocompletion but I am able to continue and select suggestions etc.

Do you know what it's related to?

Have any of you encountered this issue as well?

Comment: I'm getting this error when editing JavaScript while using tsserver. Strangely it doesn't happen with other file types for me.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem.
I'm using `nvim-cmp` for completion.
In my case, removing `omni` from sources solved the problem.

But I haven't looked into this problem so much, just found out the hotfix by randomly disabling my configs.

Comment: Removing `omni` also solves the problem for me.